# Data source not recognized while using using Easymock

Tags: java, datasource, easymock

Inside parent class BaseDAO.java, I have a method:

```
public DBWrapper getDBWrapper() {
    //Obtains the DBwrapper with the data source details
}
```

//Inside child class ChildDAO, I have a method:

```
public int getBookRefCode(int bookId) {
    //I am calling getDBWrapper.executeQuery() to execute query on my database
}
```

In JUnit test class:
I have created instance of both Child and Base class

```
BaseDAO dao = new BaseDAO();
ChildDAO cdao = new ChildDAO;

dao = createMock(BaseDAO.class);
@Test
int res = cdao.getBookRefCode(id);// This does not return any result and says data source is not recognized
```

But when, the getDBWrapper implementation is directly in child class and I do

```
cdao = createMock(ChildDAO.class); //it works
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In below code,

```
dao = createMock(BaseDAO.class);
```

what you are creating is `Proxy` for class/interface `BaseDAO` which returns default value (which you can change mocking/stubbing method call)

now, when you do

```
@Test
int res = cdao.getBookRefCode(id);// This does not return any result and says data source is not recognized
```

you're actually calling method on reference which is pointing to `ChildDAO` class which will call to real datasource, but when you mock the child class it will return mocked value, thats why this works..

```
cdao = createMock(ChildDAO.class); //it work
```

You can either mock base class OR child class depending upon what you're trying.. I mean if you are passing this Mock class to some other method/class which expects base class or child class...

Update:
You have to mock `DBWrapper` instance and inject it to your parent/child class OR you can mock `getDBWrapper` method which return mock instance

```
obj = mock(YourClass.class)
 when(obj).getdbwrapper().return(mockDbWrapper)
```

Sorry I'm on phone, pl execuse syntax

Comment: Thank you for your response! Now that my DB wrapper implementation is in parent class and the child class method simply accesses it to fetch query results, how to do the mocking? I mean mocking child class doesn't work either (it only works when the wrapper implementation is in child class)

Comment: See my updated answer, you have to mock db wrapper in this case